# Retrieve saved variable values from anonymous function

Tags: matlab

For example, [taken from Matlab](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-71621):

```
a = 1.3;
b = .2;
c = 30;
parabola = @(x) a*x.^2 + b*x + c;
```

`parabola` can be called even if `a`, `b`, `c` are removed from the workspace. The explanation is:

> Because a, b, and c are available at the time you create parabola, the function handle includes those values. The values persist within the function handle even if you clear the variables:

After an anonymous function like `parabola` is created, how do I later retrieve or see the variables stored inside it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`functions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/functions.html?searchHighlight=functions) function to get information about an anonymous function including the internal workspace in which those variables are defined.

```
a = 1.3;
b = .2;
c = 30;
parabola = @(x) a*x.^2 + b*x + c;

clear a b c

F = functions(parabola);
variables = F.workspace{1};

%// variables =
%// 
%//     a: 1.3
%//     b: 0.2
%//     c: 30
```

The workspace contains a `struct` with a field for each variable that is contained within the function handle's workspace.